# No Logcat output for certain device in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I realize that this question has basically been asked ad infinitum, but I haven't been able to find a solution that works for my case.

I'm using Android Studio 1.5, debugging on a LG-MS770, running Android 4.2.2.

The other devices I have tested with function perfectly (HTC One M8, Samsung Galaxy S5, Note 4, multiple others, along with numerous virtual device configurations), but this phone produces absolutely zero Logcat output. There is nothing for my application, nor any other processes running on the device. If it's relevant, the other measurements in the Android Monitor (Network, Memory, CPU, GPU) all output fine.

I've ensured that debugging is enabled through USB. (I can step through breakpoints, but `Log.d("TAG","log")` shows nothing.

I've also tried the usual fixes to this issue: restarting logcat, making sure the filter is set correctly, running `adb kill-server` & `adb start-server`, disconnected and reconnected the device, restarting Android Studio and my PC, all to no avail.

Does anyone know any other solutions to try? Or perhaps something specific to this device?

Thanks!

EDIT:

The device is rooted, and has a [custom rom](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwqrLkcMo7PgTEN2VVBvQm9HckU/edit) based on CyanogenMod 11

`adb logcat -d` prints the following:

`reloc_library[1331]: 20370 cannot locate 'android_log_setColoredOutput'... CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE`

Is this related to the custom rom?

Comment: Android Studio 1.5 is still in beta state, did you try using 1.4?

Comment: Yep, I had this issue back in 1.4 as well. I just tried version 1.3 and was met with the same problem.

Comment: If you can't get any output with "adb logcat -d" I would guess it is a device (Kernel) issue.
Try to reset the device, update Android or install a custom rom...

Comment: It actually does have a custom rom installed, I added the output of `adb logcat -d` to my post

Comment: Your custom rom is not correct. It is missing a resource/packet for colored output. Try updating it. This should fix the issue...

Comment: I think you're right! I'm using the newest version of this rom however, so it looks like I'm stuck. I might try a different rom, but I should be able to make due with logs from my other devices for testing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is with your custom ROM. It has an incompatible "liblog.so" included. I guess it is not a official build from CyanogenMod.

I would recommend updating to Android 5.0. I found a ROM here:
http://androidforums.com/threads/rom-v5-0-lolipop-nightly-for-lg-motion-ms770.882980/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this setting is saved, when you close the Android Studio. But may be there are some characters in your search box for the logcat.
If it is not empty, it will try to search for the String in the log, if it is one that is never used, you wont see anything...

Comment: Not a bad piece of advice, but this isn't the issue in my case. The search box is empty, and the logs work on other devices.

Answer (score 0):

Some devices actually "disable" log messages from levels "lower" than INFO, so DEBUG and VERBOSE messages won't show up by default.

You must run the `/system/bin/setprop log.debug_level 1` command from adb shell to "flip the switch".

This only lasts until you reboot the device.

Comment: This didn't seem to help.. There are also no ERROR level messages appearing when the app crashes, but there are on other devices

Comment: it says permission denied